Where is the console in intellij IDEA
I am using React to create a simple app in Intellij IDEA. I simply cannot find anywhere that something logged to the console will display.
Here is my simple code
import './App.css';

function App() {
 const handleClick = () => {
   console.log("Hello World");
 }

 return (
   <div className="App">
     <header className="App-header">
       <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
     </header>
   </div>
 );
}

export default App;

Where in the IDE (or anywhere else) can I see the Hello World pop out? I have tried the Debug window in View->Tool Windows->Debug.

Where are you running this? Presumably in a separate browser?

Correct - localhost:3000

If the actual Javascript code is executing in the browser, then you need to look at the browser's console. console.log doesn't magically send the log back to IntelliJ.

Thank you!!!!! You have no idea how long I have been searching for that answer...
If you post as answer I can accept it.

Since this is using React, the console.log output should show up in your browser's Inspector window. On most browsers, you can right-click anywhere in the webpage, and click "Inspect" in the menu.
However, if you're just looking for the IntelliJ IDEA terminal, you can check both your left and right sidebars for this icon:

If you can't find it, you can also open View > Tool Windows > Terminal.
